# How can I downgrade the OpenEmu core for Mupen64Plus?

Tags: macos, emulation, nintendo-64

I have an older Mac with Intel HD graphics.  I have the same issues described in [this OpenEmu issue](https://github.com/OpenEmu/OpenEmu/issues/3447), where Nintendo 64 games, which worked fine in earlier versions of OpenEmu, are now having performance issues, running slowly with choppy audio.

[This OpenEmu Mupen64Plus core issue](https://github.com/OpenEmu/Mupen64Plus-Core/issues/25) indicates that downgrading the Mupen64Plus core from 2.5.4 to 2.5.3 resolves the problem.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This procedure worked for me:

1. Download the desired version zip file from [the release page of the OpenEmu Mupen64Plus core GitHub project](https://github.com/OpenEmu/Mupen64Plus-Core/releases)
2. Stop OpenEmu
3. Delete the current Mupen64Plus core; for instance run the following in Terminal: `rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/OpenEmu/Cores/Mupen64Plus.oecoreplugin/`
4. Unzip the downloaded core in the same location; for instance `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/OpenEmu/Cores/ ; unzip ~/Downloads/Mupen64Plus_2.5.3.zip`

I suspect OpenEmu won't and can't guarantee that it will always work to downgrade to older cores like this, but it resolved my issue completely this time.